# PHP Location redirect contains file name index.html

Tags: php, html, redirect

When my simple apache webserver hits index.php it redirects to index.html however in the url instead of rooturl.com its example.com/index.html. Is there a simple way to fix this?

`header( 'Location: /index.hmtl') ;`

www.example.com

Comment: This sounds like a server configuration problem, not a PHP programming issue.

Comment: This php file is the first thing the server hits when someone navigates to my domain. It routes the user to this URL. I still want the redirect but without the filename in the url

Comment: You mean `header("Location: /");` ?

Comment: Sorry if im not explaining myself correctly. This PHP file is the entry point. I have two index files with different languages that get redirected based on browser language. I want the redirect to happen without the file name tact on the end.

Comment: That won't work if the server defaults to `index.php` when there's no filename, since you'll just keep redirecting to the PHP file. You have to put a filename if you want it to redirect to a different page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can only be 1 default directory index file. Either `http://example.com/` resolves as `http://example.com/index.html` or `http://example.com/index.php`. You can't have both work at the same time.

Instead of redirect to different index.html for different language, I think you should consider to directly include the HTML file. For example,

```php
<?php

// index.php
switch (some_get_user_language_func()) {
  case 'en':
    include './index.en.html';
  case 'es':
    include './index.es.html';
  case 'fr':
    include './index.fr.html';
  default:
    include './index.en.html';
}
```

Alternatively, you may try Apache's [mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_negotiation.html) to switch HTML file without the index.php file.